# Solidity: How to replace specific string position with letter?

Tags: solidity, string, returndata

I would like to replace a letter at a specific position of a string with another letter.

```
function _stringReplace(string memory _string, uint256 _pos, string memory _letter) internal pure returns (string memory) {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solidity doesn't manage strings but you can use this function I've written for you :

```
 function _stringReplace(string memory _string, uint256 _pos, string memory _letter) internal pure returns (string memory) {
        bytes memory _stringBytes = bytes(_string);
        bytes memory result = new bytes(_stringBytes.length);

  for(uint i = 0; i < _stringBytes.length; i++) {
        result[i] = _stringBytes[i];
        if(i==_pos)
         result[i]=bytes(_letter)[0];
    }
    return  string(result);
 }
```

if you call it for example with "hello",0,"y"  will return "yello"
[image]